# Why do goroutines not execute until the for-loop has terminated?

Tags: go, goroutine

Like most of you, I'm familiar with the fact that Go reuses the iterator variable in a for-loop, so closures for each goroutine will capture the same variable. A typical example of this the following code which will always print the final value of the loop from each goroutine:

```
func main() {
    for i := 0; i < 5; i++ {
        go func() {
            fmt.Println(i) // prints 5 each time
        }()
    }
    time.Sleep(100 * time.Millisecond)
}
```

What I haven't been able to find an explanation of, is why the goroutines do not execute until after the loop is completed. Even the following code produces the value of `ii` as `10` which is set *after* the goroutine is called:

```
func main() {
    for i := 0; i < 5; i++ {
        ii := i
        go func() {
            fmt.Println(ii) // prints 10 each time...!
        }()
        ii = 10
    }
    time.Sleep(100 * time.Millisecond)
}
```

The closest thing to an explanation I've read is that for-loops typically execute faster than goroutines. This raises two questions for me: 1. Is that true? 2. Why?

Comment: "produces the value of ii as 10 which is set after the goroutine is called" goroutiness are not "called". It's better to say `go f()` "creates" a new goroutine which will execute f once the goroutine actually starts running.

Comment: "The closest thing to an explanation I've read is that for-loops typically execute faster than goroutines. This raises two questions for me: 1. Is that true?" Yes! No! It's nonsensical to compare for loops which are executed by a goroutine and goroutines in regard to speed. Every code is executed by a goroutine: Your for-loop is executed by the goroutine executing main. Yes this is a goroutine too (it's spawned during program startup, not manualy with `go`).

Comment: What happens: The main goroutine is happily working on your for loop. This loop does some variable asignments and spawns some goroutines. By mere chance (there are **absolutely no guarantees** on how goroutines are scheduled) the main goroutine reaches time.Sleep before any of the fresh goroutines started doing their Printf work. Without syncronisation (channesl, mutex, waitgroups, etc), any order of goroutine execution might happen.

Comment: And: It is wrong to reason about a program with a race condition.

Comment: @Volker Thanks for your patience in correcting my (many) misunderstandings. You mention that "by mere chance" the goroutine reaches time.Sleep before the goroutines execute the Println statement. I understand why this *should* be mere chance, but running this code very reliably produces the same result. Shouldn't I expect to see more variation in the results? E.g. https://play.golang.org/p/PA4veXPOd6W

Comment: There are NO GUARANTIES whatsoever. Not even that you shouldn‘t get the same result everytime. You are thinking about smth you cannot reason about (from a language perspective). Your code is unsynchronised and thats all to know. It may produce any result anytime.

Answer (score 2):

***Never*** assume the order of execution when dealing with more than one goroutine - no matter how tempting it may be. Don't put in sleeps; don't call [runtime.Gosched](https://pkg.go.dev/runtime#Gosched); don't assume *anything*.

The only guaranteed way to ensure order of execution is via synchronization methods such as channels, `sync.Mutex`, `sync.WaitGroups` etc.

Answer (score 2):

Anything is possible because the program has a data race.

Setting aside the data race, there's no evidence that the goroutines execute after the for loop is completed. The value 10 is assigned to `ii` in the statement after the goroutine is started, not after the for loop.

The memory model allows for the compiler to optimize the two `ii` assignments to a single assignment at the start of the for loop body. It could be that the goroutines execute immediately, but the goroutines see the value of 10 from the optimization.

Comment: As Volker pointed out, I was starting from false assumptions. Your explanation of optimization makes sense to me and accounts for why running this code produces the exact same result every time (even though in principle it could vary).

Answer (score 0):

you should use the goroutine like this:

```
package main

import "fmt"
import "time"

func main() {
    for i := 0; i < 5; i++ {
        ii := i
        go func(k int) {
            fmt.Println(k) // prints 10 each time...!
        }(ii)
        ii = 10
    }
    time.Sleep(100 * time.Millisecond)
}
```

Comment: Indeed that will fix the problem. But my question was why it prints 10 to begin with!

Comment: @vordhosbn you can use `runtime.Gosched` to prevent the forloop goroutine run first:  https://play.golang.org/p/y5w1unj9mpx

Comment: @lidaobing careful! From the [runtime.Gosched](https://pkg.go.dev/runtime#Gosched) docs `Gosched yields the processor, allowing other goroutines to run. It does not suspend the current goroutine, so execution resumes automatically.` - so running this is not a guaranteed fix.

Comment: @colm.anseo it's not a fix, but an explanation on how goroutine works.